# Annotation Protocol compatible annotations?

Tags: html, web-browser, firefox, annotation

I am looking for a browser extension that allows for [W3C Web Annotation Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/annotation-protocol/) compatible annotations on locally stored HTML pages. My favourite browser is Firefox, so add-ons for Firefox would be especially appreciated.

Basically, I need an Add-on that transform my browser into an annotation editor that can write these annotations to a file and can also show them.

Any advice is very appreciated!